# How to tag any document when send for signing through Docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

I need to tag document with self defined attributes to later identify the document when Docusign connect sends a response in form of envelope to my callback listener. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use DocuSign's feature called **Custom Fields**.  You can create them through the Classic DocuSign Experience (ie. the older web UI) so you might have to switch back to the Classic experience from your Preferences drop down.

**Custom Fields** are fields that are set at the envelope level and they will be returned in the meta data that the DocuSign Connect module sends.  You can create the fields through the Web Console OR you can create them through the API.

Here is the description from the documentation:

"*These fields can be used to record information about the envelope, help search for envelopes and track information. The custom fields are shown in the Message window when a user is creating an envelope. The custom fields are not seen by the envelope recipients.*"

Here is a how-to guide on how to create them through the older UI i.e. the Classic DocuSign experience (currently not supported through the new UI):

https://www.docusign.com/support/classic/documentation/cdse-admin-guide/account-admin/envelope-custom-fields

NOTE: Make sure you enable the **Show** checkbox on the field in order to see it during the envelope creation process through the web console.

For info on how to create and use custom fields through the API see these API Calls:

[Add Custom Fields](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Add%20Envelope%20Custom%20Fields%20to%20an%20Envelope.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____49)

[Get Custom Fields Info](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Custom%20Field%20Information.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____50)

[Modify Envelope Custom Fields](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Modify%20Envelope%20Custom%20Fields%20for%20an%20Envelope.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____51)

[Remove Custom Fields](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Remove%20Envelope%20Custom%20Fields%20from%20an%20Envelope.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____52)